# purposes(intention) of the inversion of normal word order

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

> Is it better to make important life decisions on your own or is it better to consult other people?
>
> > There are good reasons for both, **I suppose**. Ultimately, it’s your life so I suppose you should make the decisions. On the other hand, any decisions you make can affect other people so it seems only right to discuss things with others first. Like many philosophical questions, there’s no simple answer, **I’m afraid**.

**I suppose** there are good reasons for both.
There are good reasons for both, **I suppose**.

**I’m afraid** there’s no simple answer.
there’s no simple answer, **I’m afraid**.

Sometimes I hear these kinds of inversions. I think meanings of them are the same. Is there any difference in speaker's intention or purpose?

Comment: You mean “purpose,” not “porpose” (or “porpoise”!), I assume.

Answer (score 1):

In your example pairs, the meaning is the same. But it's possible to run into idiomatic differences. *I'm afraid* means *I fear* in the front position, so

> I'm afraid there's a monster under your bed

means that I'm fearful of a monster under a particular bed.

But *I'm afraid* in the trailing positions, i.e, almost as an aside, means "I have some bad news." Thus,

> There's a monster under your bed, I'm afraid

means that I have bad news for you about a monster, namely that it's close by. But it needn't be a problem for me.

Comment: The first can be read in the same way as the second, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Lawrence Right. I heard that we can start with "I'm afraid" to say bad news.